# Conditional combination of string column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the sample -

```
                          tmp3
177          SADHASHIV CHINORE
249  MADHUSUMAN WADIKHAYE PLOT
250  MADHUSUMAN WADIKHAYE PLOT
260              SUKHRAM YADAV
404      BANGALORE RURAL DISTK
405      BANGALORE RURAL DISTK
784         chhotu mahto gosai
854              SUKHPAL HOUSE
855              SUKHPAL HOUSE
857                ANIL VASULE
```

Here is the expected output -

```
                          tmp3
177          SADHASHIV CHINORE
249          MADHUSUMAN WADIKHAYE
250          MADHUSUMAN WADIKHAYE
260          SUKHRAM YADAV
404          BANGALORE RURAL DISTK
405          BANGALORE RURAL DISTK
784          chhotu mahto gosai
854          SUKHPAL
855          SUKHPAL
857          ANIL VASULE
```

Goal is to replace certain words by looking up a list. The list is long but we can assume the below for brevity's sake -

```
words = ['PLOT', 'HOUSE']
```

**What I've tried**

```
df_r['tmp3'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split() if i in words]))
```

This is inefficient as it's a large `df`.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
words = ['PLOT', 'HOUSE']
#your list of n elements
```

via [`Series.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
df['tmp3']=df['tmp3'].replace('|'.join(words),'',regex=True)
#If you want to replace in whole df then use:
#df=df.replace('|'.join(words),'',regex=True)
```

OR

via [`Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['tmp3']=df['tmp3'].str.replace('|'.join(words),'',regex=True)
```